# how to compile netcdf

Tags: c, netcdf

Hello I am using given code from the examples to test if I have installed netcdf correctly. I installed the prebuilt netCDF4.8.1-NC4-DAP-64 and put it in the environment variable path (I checked to make sure it worked, it did. Next I did #include "netcdf.h" in the main c file and then made the make file as such:

```
CC = gcc 
EXECUTABLES = try
INCLUDES = -IC:/Program\ Files/netCDF\ 4.8.1/include/
CFLAGS = $(INCLUDES)
LIBS = -LC:/Program\ Files/netCDF\ 4.8.1/lib -lnetcdf -lmfhdf -ljpeg -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lz -lm
all: $(EXECUTABLES)

try: try.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o try try.c $(LIBS)
clean:
    rm core $(EXECUTABLES) *.o
```

I tried to look at forums and added diffrent flags such as all of
`-lnetcdf -lpnetcdf -lmfhdf -ldf -ljpeg -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lz -lsz -lm`
but it would throw

```
gcc  -IC:/Program\ Files/netCDF\ 4.8.1/include/ -o try try.c -LC:/Program\ Files/netCDF\ 4.8.1/lib -lnetcdf -lpnetcdf -lmfhdf -ldf -ljpeg -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lz -lsz -lm
C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpnetcdf
C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ldf
C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsz
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:10: try] Error 1
```

so I removed theose flags and kept the rest but got the error:

```
gcc  -IC:/Program\ Files/netCDF\ 4.8.1/include/ -o try try.c -LC:/Program\ Files/netCDF\ 4.8.1/lib -lnetcdf -lmfhdf -ljpeg -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lz -lm
C:\Users\NPAT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAbmx3N.o:try.c:(.text+0xa3): undefined reference to `nc_create'
C:\Users\NPAT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAbmx3N.o:try.c:(.text+0xc3): undefined reference to `nc_strerror'   
C:\Users\NPAT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAbmx3N.o:try.c:(.text+0x109): undefined reference to `nc_def_dim'   
C:\Users\NPAT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAbmx3N.o:try.c:(.text+0x129): undefined reference to `nc_strerror'  
C:\Users\NPAT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAbmx3N.o:try.c:(.text+0x16f): undefined reference to `nc_def_dim'   
C:\Users\NPAT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAbmx3N.o:try.c:(.text+0x18f): undefined reference to `nc_strerror'  
C:\Users\NPAT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAbmx3N.o:try.c:(.text+0x204): undefined reference to `nc_def_var'   
C:\Users\NPAT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAbmx3N.o:try.c:(.text+0x224): undefined reference to `nc_strerror'  
C:\Users\NPAT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAbmx3N.o:try.c:(.text+0x24f): undefined reference to `nc_enddef'    
C:\Users\NPAT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAbmx3N.o:try.c:(.text+0x26f): undefined reference to `nc_strerror'  
C:\Users\NPAT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAbmx3N.o:try.c:(.text+0x2ad): undefined reference to `nc_put_var_int'
C:\Users\NPAT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAbmx3N.o:try.c:(.text+0x2cd): undefined reference to `nc_strerror'  
C:\Users\NPAT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAbmx3N.o:try.c:(.text+0x2f8): undefined reference to `nc_close'     
C:\Users\NPAT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAbmx3N.o:try.c:(.text+0x318): undefined reference to `nc_strerror'  
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:10: try] Error 1
```

Any help is appreciated, Thank You

Comment: What files are present inside `C:/Program\ Files/netCDF\ 4.8.1/lib`?

Comment: cmake     hdf5_cpp.lib     hdf5_tools.lib   libhdf.lib       libhdf5_hl.lib      libmfhdf.lib        mfhdf.lib   xdr.lib
hdf.lib   hdf5_hl.lib      jpeg.lib         libhdf5.lib      libhdf5_hl_cpp.lib  libnetcdf.settings  netcdf.lib  zlib.lib
hdf5.lib  hdf5_hl_cpp.lib  libcurl_imp.lib  libhdf5_cpp.lib  libhdf5_tools.lib   libxdr.lib          pkgconfig   zlibstatic.lib

Answer (score 0):

Update!! I think that because the files I was trying to link were .lib, gcc was not linking it. I changed form vscode to vs community and added the .lib and it started to work properly.

Instead of compiling with gcc I compiled with MSVC.

Comment: So you compiled with MSVC instead of GCC right?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).